# How do I make sure that a snakemake rule is only exectuted sequentially

Tags: snakemake

I have one rule at the end of my snakemake workflow which should only run sequentially for its tasks. So it should not be run in parallel working on its tasks.

So it should be blocked when it is exectued and be freed when done with a task.

The reason is, that the rule is writing to a database which should not be accessed too many times in parallel.

Idealy there will also be a delay of a second or so between the calls.

How do I do this?

I did read docs and googled but did not find if there is any feature like this.

Answer (score 0):

Since `snakefile` is a Python script, you can implement custom logic using Python built-ins. For example:

```py
from time import sleep


# run 10 times (or as many as is necessary)
for iteration in range(10):
   sleep(1)  # the 1 second delay between sequential executions
   rule:
      name: f'custom_step_{iteration}'
      ...  # the rest of the rule logic
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply answer your question, you can use a resource to limit how many instances will run.  Call it `db_connections` and run snakemake with `--resources db_connections=1`.  Your rule is then:

```
rule write_db:
    resources:
        db_connections=1
```

The sleep logic will have to be built into your shell or run directive.

Alternatively, since snakemake only cares about files as inputs/outputs, you will also have to use a flag file to signal a rule has run.  You can use that to wire together your rules but some of the logic gets more complicated.

I think @SultanOrazbayev's answer will just throttle the parsing of the snakefile but otherwise not affect its execution.